# How to bind a user and ensure they are in the correct group?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I think what I am trying to do is fairly simple, I want to setup ldap so that incoming binds check that the password is correct and the user is a member of a specific group.

Running the following query yields the following

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b uid=myname,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com dn memberof
```

Result

```
dn: uid=myname,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

I have tried the following query

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://localhost" -D "(&(cn=My Name)(memberOf=cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))" -W -b "dc=example,dc=com"
```

ldapsearch keeps throwing the following error

```
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: invalid DN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this answer enough or do you encounter any other issue? Typically for entry look up we use a technical account to bind to the directory. Are you required to bind with the same user for which you want to check the entry (meaning you don't know if this user has enough permission to search through the entire DIT) ?

Comment: @EricLavault, your answer got me on the right track, tweaked the command as you suggested and it worked. I also use a non human service account for the bind, I kept putting the filter as the bind! It makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things to fix in your search query :

- the *filter* part should be placed after all options and before the list of *attributes* if any.
- the *-D option* requires an argument, a *bind dn* to bind to the LDAP directory.

In other words : `ldapsearch -x -H <ldapuri> -D <binddn> -W -b <basedn> <filter>`

Assuming you can use this bind dn `cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com`, you should end up with a query looking like this :

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://localhost" -D "cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(&(cn=My Name)(memberOf=cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch